# change workspace path in 'workflow script from scm'

Tags: jenkins, workflow, jenkins-workflow

How can I change the default workspace if I run the workflow through script from SCM? ( tried the 'ws' inside groovy script but it seems not to work in this case - otherwise it worked for me in 'workflow script' mode )

Answer (score 1):

```
checkout scm: [$class: "SubversionSCM", locations: [[
            remote: srcUrl, credentiaolsId: cid, clean: true, FilePath: '.']]]
```

FilePath : you can declare the path to checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dir` step to change directories, generally inside the standard workspace. Or you can use the `ws` step to allocate an entirely new workspace in a different location. What specifically did not work for you?